# ios CLLocation didUpdateLocations error

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am use XCode7.2 Version

I try to use the locationManager delegate function

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
 print("%f/%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)

 }
```

But I get the error below:

```
  Downcast from 'CLLocation?' to 'CLLocation' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?
```

I don't know how to fix the problem .

The swift code change more

have anyone can help me how to fix?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locations.last` return type is `CLLocation?` and thats because an array may have no elements at all. As error state you don't have to cast an optional type to non optional when you can just unwrap it by doing this:

```
let location = locations.last!
```

Be aware that using the above method can lead to exception and always consider using optional unwrapping

```
if let location = locations.last{
    print("%f/%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. If I use optional, I will get other error:        var location? : CLLocation = locations.last  the error:show: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: You are using optional in wrong way. It should be `var location : CLLocation? = ...`

Comment: sorry, I got other error...Orz....
var location : CLLocation? = locations.last
       
        lngLb.text = String(format:"%f", (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        latLb.text = String(format:"%f", (location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
it will show the error:  Variable 'location' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

Comment: @dickfala check the edited answer. Thats an optional unwrapping that Im suggesting for you